# Solving infinite sums with primes.

Tags: prime-numbers, pi, infinite-product

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$'th prime number.

How would one go about proving that infinite products like: $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty1 - \frac{1}{(p_k)^2} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$$

or

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{{p_k}^2}{{p_k}^2 - 1} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
are correct?

Is there any way to prove it except by exhaustion?

Comment: How do you mean "by exhaustion"?

Comment: @IgorRivin As in "proof by exhaustion"

Comment: "Proof by exhaustion" consists of trying every case.  That is, you would find every one of the infinite number of primes, and then compute the product, and show that it is equal to that number.  That is probably not what *you* mean, but it is what "proof by exhaustion" means in this case.

Comment: @anorton that would be exhausting, but probably not very effective in proving the result.

Comment: @IgorRivin True--but that's the only remotely possible interpretation of "by exhaustion" I can think of in this instance... ;)

Comment: Four color theorem was proven by exhaustion, using 1936 cases...

Comment: @JohnWO Yes, but how would you even break these products into cases?  You cannot list all the primes...

Comment: @anorton "You cannot list all the primes" - Exactly, thus the question...

Answer (score 4):

Well,

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-1/p_k^2} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac1{p_k^j}.$$ Formally expanding the product of sums, and using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, you get 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}6.$$

But maybe that is an argument by exhaustion?

Comment: No, it's perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: This is **exactly** what I thought of when I saw that exhaustion thing in the OP and comment,  yet the OP liked it, so...

Answer (score 1):

As @doppz mentioned in the comments, the way to prove these identities is to realize the requested product is requesting the value of $\zeta(2)$.  Then, you can use any of the multitude of proofs that $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

For example proofs: http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/MathGradTalkZeta2.pdf

Comment: That was not the question...

Comment: @JohnWO Um... yes it was, but perhaps I didn't explain every step.  Igor's answer shows that the second product in your question can be changed into a sum.  That sum happens to be $\zeta(2)$.  Thus, if you can prove the value of $\zeta(2)$, you have proven the value of the product.

Comment: "Igor's answer shows that the product can be changed into a sum." Which answered my question...

Comment: @JohnWO You asked how to *prove*, not how to change into a sum.  I agree Igor answered the question (by giving one proof), but I answered with an additional, general outline of another approach, which is a bit more "Googleable" if you want more information about the problems.

Answer (score 0):

In general we have the following [Euler formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$

and since $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ , [see this wiki](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeta2.html)

so we get the result.