# What is the value of this Infinite Product of prime numbers expression?

Tags: calculus, prime-numbers, infinite-product

What is the value of:

$$\prod_1^\infty \frac{p_i^2}{p_i^2 -1
}$$ Where $$p_i$$ are the prime numbers: 2, 3, ...

Comment: [Its a direct proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function?newwindow=true)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621918/solving-infinite-sums-with-primes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is $\pi^2/6$.

Here are two steps to take (made edit to the equation):

- $\frac{p^2}{p^2-1} = \frac{1}{1 - p^{-2}}$
- $\frac{1}{1 - p^{-2}} = \sum_{j \ge 0} p^{-2j}$.

Now, taking the product of all these sums you get $\sum_{n \ge 1} n^{-2}$. 
For the last you likely know the value; if not I recalled it above.

Comment: @Moti thanks for the edit. I should have spotted that. Just to be sure, the original would not converge as the signs would "flip" all the time.

Comment: I do not know what would have happened with my original error but clearly the answer would be different. I believe that the flipping will converge to +/- π^2/6.

Comment: @Moti yes the absolute value of the terms would approach $\pi^2/6$ and the sign woudl flip. And the product would thus *not* converge. Just like the sequecen $+1,-1,+1, -1, \dots$ does not converge.